# Which loss function to use if entries in a prediction span multiple orders of magnitude?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions, error

I am modeling the rates of chemical reactions with a ML-model (specifically a neural network with a lowish number of parameters). However, the rates (or technically the formation rates), the predictions, span multiple orders of magnitude in absolute values with differing signs and including zero. Each prediction consists of a vector of rates. So one sample from a batch of typical training data might look like

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1.3\mathrm{e}{-12} & -3.9\mathrm{e}{-8} & 7.6\mathrm{e}{-5} & 0.00
\end{bmatrix}.$$

That means that inside one target vector the values differ by orders of magnitude. However, the values between two targets are (mostly) in the same order of magnitude.

My big problem is to accurately and robustly determine the 'error' of one of my predictions to ensure they are right, even across multiple orders of magnitude. My attempts so far include

- **absolute error** e.g. L1/L2-norm: They fail for obvious reasons. The absolute biggest term in the prediction dictates the error and predictions for small values can be wrong by orders of magnitudes.
- **relative error** e.g. MRE: They fail for the presence of zeros in my predictions so are not applicable as is but have to be extended with a threshold for example.
- **thresholded relative error** e.g.$|\frac{\hat{y}_i-y_i}{\max(|y_i|,t_i)}|$: fixes the zero issue but the choice of threshold can be arbitrary and does not guarantee good performance.
- **logarithmic scaling for error calculation**: same problem as with relative errors except worse because predictions might be negative.

So far I have not been able to find a good compromise and I see the consequences in finding good approximations for the more dominant rates and very poor results for the smaller ones.

Are there any more reliable/meaningful error measures I am missing?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a multivariate outcome? That is, do you aim to predict a vector of values (which differ by orders of magnitude) for each set of feature values?

Comment: @Dave, that is exactly what I'm trying to communicate. Please excuse my lacking mathematics skills xD But yes, you are right, now that you metioned it I remember again.

Comment: [This answer of mine on Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/109504/73930) could be worth a read. I plan to expand on that in an answer here later today, but the gist is that you have to define what the misses are, and considering the $\ell_2$ norm isn’t working for you.

Comment: @mkt I implemented the cube-root-transformation for both training samples and the predictions followed by calculating the L1-norm and am satisfied with the looks of it. However my model is seemingly not, because training yields rather high losses. Compared to the untransformed model it scores even worse. Hereby 'worse' is measured by some different, physically interpretable metric, of which I'm confident to be 'the best' for judging performance. Unfortunately, this metric is not accessible to me during training but can only be calculated during inference since it involves ODE solving etc..

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you might benefit immensely from scaling your outcomes to put them on more even footing. This way, the large values in one variable do not dominate the work. This is completely legitimate, as it is equivalent to a unit conversion (such as meters to kilometers).

Two ideas come to mind.

1. Force all outcomes to be in the interval $[0,1]$ by subtracting the minimum value and then dividing by the range. You can then apply the inverse transformation to predictions on this scale to get predictions on the original scale. If you have holdout data, you would apply the same transformation you used on the training data, not the transformation based on the minimum and range of the holdout data.
2. Standardize each variable by subtracting its mean and then dividing by its standard deviation. This forces the transformed variables to all have means of zero and standard deviations of one. If you have holdout data, you would apply the same transformation you used on the training data, not the transformation based on the maximum and range of the holdout data.

After applying transformations such as these, you may find the usual loss functions to work much better. Neither of these are assured to work, but they might, and I hope they spark some ideas if they do not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't think a simple rescaling (as in unit conversion) will help, because it will scale all values equally thus conserving relative size differences. I am experimenting with the above mentioned asinh-transformation which looks really promising. However, since my values are rather small I'd like to rescale the inputs multiplicatively first ($\sinh^{-1}(kx)$), but with what value? Making it arbitrarily big somewhat works, but is it motivated? I don't know...